# Clarification on whether pycharm can insert a Google docstring skeleton

Tags: pycharm

I am using Pycharm Professional 2016.1 build 145.844. I have seen the documentation for Pycharm being able to insert Google Docstrings into code. I have set the project settings in pycharm to use google docstrings, etc. However, whenever I try to create a docstring by typing `"""` I don't see a fully formatted Google docstring. I generally just see some space and then the word `Returns.`

```
File --> Settings --> Tools --> Python Integrated Tools
```

So I just wanted to clarify, does pycharm insert a full Google Docstring skeleton when you enter `"""`? Or is this just that pycharm will read a formatted Google Docstring when it goes to create the Sphinx documentation? I was really just looking for clarification on what the behavior should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it depends a bit on what do you mean by `fully formated` `skeleton` (and thus what your expectations are in this respect) :)

The behaviour you describe suggests what pycharm inserts for a function *with no arguments* or with just `self` as argument.

This is, for example, what I get auto-inserted for a function with arguments (still on 5.0.3 Pro version):

```
def __init__(self, db_data=None, db_key=None, url_key=None, key_id=None, parent=None):
    """

    Args:
        db_data:
        db_key:
        url_key:
        key_id: 
        parent:

    Returns:

    """
```

Which some may consider an acceptable skeleton ...

Comment: Cool, I get that. I think I was creating the skeleton before entering the parameter names into the parenthesis. Thanks for the tip.